# 6 Cd Changer to Aux Out in 2005 Honda Pilot

Tags: honda, audio, electronics, pilot

I am thinking about replacing my 2005 Honda Pilot's stock stereo with a Pioneer AVH-X5800BHS stereo but I want to keep my 6 Cd changer. Is there a module that will plug into the harness coming out of the 6 CD changer and convert it into an Aux out that I can just plug into the back of my aftermarket stereo?

Comment: @SteveRacer - We've already stated [car audio questions](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1346/4152) are on topic for this site.

Comment: No, you can't just plug it into an Aux port because the cd changer needs commands to know what to do. The head unit controls which cd plays, skips, pause, play, etc... Most of the time this command protocol is proprietary and only the factory head unit is able to communicate with the cd changer.

Comment: If it won't work, does anyone know of an aftermarket 6 CD changer that will fit and is compatible with the AF headunit?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2   The very thread you listed made the distinction of *problems* with OEM stock equipment, not accessory upgrade paths.  I honestly didn't think the question would get the best answer here... but it seems @_cory has answered it, and should probably make that comment into an answer.

Comment: @SteveRacer - The point is, accessories, which includes electronics, is on topic for the site.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Whatever.  That's not what the meta thread you cited concluded, but I'm easy.  I deleted the close comment, and I would unvote the close if I knew how.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep my 6 Cd changer

Any particular reason?

The Pioneer system you want includes USB inputs and is fully compatible with anything in the Apple lineup and a selection of Android devices. iPods start at $150, have vastly more capacity and go in your shirt pocket instead of the trunk. If you already have an iPhone you are all set. You might even get phone handsfree support with it.

Comment: Well I couldn't find the tray to replace the CD changer and most of my songs are still on CDs...